C program for multiplying rectangular matrices using arrays prints no result matrix
I put my efforts to write a c program for multiplication of rectangular matrices, but when compiled and run the program, the resultant matrix is not printed with the products. As user inputs, I tried entering 2 rows and 3 columns for the Matrix A, and 3 rows and 2 columns for the Matrix B.
How can I correct the below code?
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,r,c,r1,c1,r2,c2,k,a[10][10],b[10][10],result[10][10];
    printf("\n Enter the no. of rows and column desired for the 1st matrix (between 1 to 10):");
    scanf("%d%d",&r1,&c1);
    printf("\n Enter the no. of rows and columns for the 2nd matrix - between 1 to 10 (Pls note that no. of rows of 1st matrix should be equal to the no. of columns in the 2nd matrix for multiplication):");
    scanf("%d%d",&r2,&c2);
    
    printf("\n Enter the elements of the 1st Matrix:");
    for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c1;j++){
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    printf("\n Print of 1st Matrix:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c1;j++){
            printf("\t%d",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("\n Enter the elements of the 2nd Matrix:");
    for(i=0;i<r2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++){
            scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    printf("\n Print of 2nd Matrix:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++){
            printf("\t%d",b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    //multiplying 1st and 2nd matrices and storing the results in results[i][j]
    for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++){
            for(k=0;k<c1;k++){
                result[i][j] = result[i][j] + (a[i][k] * b[k][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Printing the results
    printf("\n After Multiplication of two matrices:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c;j++){
            printf("\t%d",result[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}


Where do you assign values to variables r and c, that serve as the bounds in your last loop nest?

The problem description "the resultant matrix is not printed with the products that it suppose to" is not sufficient. Please [edit] your question and show the input you use, the output you get and the expected output.

You have a bit of an issue if the two matrix factors do not have properly matched shape.  Ideally, you would set up the input so that it is not possible to request a product of mismatched factors in the first place.  At minimum, you should validate.

Initialize result[10][10] = {0};

What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C? Follow that post, compile again and fix all bugs that the compiler literally points out to you. Illustration of the compiler pointing out all the bugs: https://godbolt.org/z/MKa6qKx6G

Many thanks for all the suggestions and helps. Much appreciated!

In your code there are some problems.
Result matrix  initialization
I suggest you to change the code in this way
//multiplying 1st and 2nd matrices and storing the results in results[i][j]
       for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++){

            //init i,j element of result matrix

            result[i][j] = 0;   //add here the initialisation
            for(k=0;k<c1;k++){
                
                result[i][j] = result[i][j] + (a[i][k] * b[k][j]);
            }
        }
    }

Cycle for printing output
In your code you used the variable r and c without initizialize them. this is the main cause of wrong output.
Change the code in this way:
for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++){
            printf("\t%d",result[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

The new code
Here there is the completed code of your program with corrections and some improvements in scanf statements.
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,r1,c1,r2,c2,k,a[10][10],b[10][10];
    int result[10][10];
    printf("\n Enter the no. of rows and column desired for the 1st matrix (between 1 to 10):");
    scanf("%d %d",&r1,&c1);   //put a space between escape codes in order to avoid conversion issues
    printf("\n Enter the no. of rows and columns for the 2nd matrix - between 1 to 10 (Pls note that no. of rows of 1st matrix should be equal to the no. of columns in the 2nd matrix for multiplication):");
    scanf("%d %d",&r2,&c2);   //put a space between escape codes in order to avoid conversion issues
    
    printf("\n Enter the elements of the 1st Matrix:");
    for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c1;j++){
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    printf("\n Print of 1st Matrix:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c1;j++){
            printf("\t%d",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("\n Enter the elements of the 2nd Matrix:");
    for(i=0;i<r2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++){
            scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    

    printf("\n Print of 2nd Matrix:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++){
            printf("\t%d",b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    //multiplying 1st and 2nd matrices and storing the results in results[i][j]
       for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++){
            //init i,j element of result matrix
            result[i][j] = 0.0;
            for(k=0;k<c1;k++){
                printf("(%d %d %d) %f - %d - %d\n",i,j,k,result[i][j],a[i][k],b[k][j]);
                result[i][j] = result[i][j] + (a[i][k] * b[k][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Printing the results
    printf("\n After Multiplication of two matrices:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++){
            printf("\t%d",result[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}


"//put a space between escape codes in order to avoid conversion issues" no, not relevant for %d conversions; maybe good for %c, or %[ conversions.

Also, without a good reason otherwise, always prefer double for floating point variables.

@pmg the space between escape codes is a (personal) good practice to guarantee more unambiguous codes but, for integer data, it works fine without space also by press enter key to say when you wrote a number. I suggested float use instead double just for "resource optimisation" :)

For user input always prefer fgets() :-)

@pmg yes, I always use fgets in C because I have more control.

@EricPostpischil you're right, I apologise for my mistake

Thank you very much N3tMaster for your kind help and support. Much appreciated!
